# Error in configuration of Mongodb sharded cluster

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have Error in configuration of Mongodb sharded cluster.

I tried all the possibilities of `rs.add("127.0.0.1:27002")`, `rs.add("loclahost:27002")` and `rs.add("hostname:27002")` for sharding

But I am getting **error:**

```
{
  "ok" : 0,
  "errmsg" : "Either all host names in a replica set configuration must be localhost references, or none must be; found 1 out of 2",
  "code" : 103 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you try to connect to your primary and trying to add the secondary nodes. To start a Mongo instance by typing

```
mongo localhost:30001
```

I suppose this is primary, in the mongod shell for this primary. Type in this command

```
rs.status()
```

You'll get to know the name of your primary. Same will be the name of your secondary with just the difference of the port number.

Once you get the name, just do `rs.add("name:port_number")` and you'll be able to add.

Answer (score 0):

`rs.add()` is used to make `ReplicaSet` not `Sharded cluster`.

If you what to add a shard to a sharded cluster, you may use `sh.addShard("host:port")`.